# How to define GraphQL input type in vue-apollo client

Tags: vuejs2, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

## Situation:

I am using [laravel-graphql](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql) as a backend GraphQL service and [vue-apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo) as a frontend client.

In my Vue component I have a gql query as follows: (relation: A Song has more SongParts)

```
const getSong = gql`
    query FetchSong ($id:Int!){
        song(id: $id) {
            id,
            name,
            authors_lyrics,
            authors_music
            song_parts{
                type
                lyrics
            }
        }
    }`;
```

Now there's a mutation that i want to use to update given song:

```
const updateSong = gql`
    mutation updateSongMutation ($id:Int!,$name:String,$authors_lyrics:String,$authors_music:String, $song_parts: [SongPart]) {
        updateSongMutation(id: $id, name: $name, authors_lyrics: $authors_lyrics, authors_music: $authors_music, song_parts: $song_parts) {
            id
        }
    }`;
```

.. and in the Vue component used this way:

```
methods: {
            save: function(){
                this.$apollo.mutate({
                    mutation: updateSong,
                    variables: this.songData,
                }).then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        },
```

However, to update the song_parts array I need to define a custom input type:

```
input SongPart{
    id: Int!
    lyrics: String
}
```

## Problem

I can't figure out, where to define this input type. When I'm using GraphiQL in Chrome WebTools, there's no problem defining it in front of the mutation. I also found some info for apollo server, but I need it in the client.

So basically the problem is about mutating a list of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input types should still be defined inside your schema on the server. I'm not that familiar with laravel, but looking at the documentation for laravel-graphql, it looks like at the moment inputs are defined just like regular types, you just set the `$inputObject` property to true. See the example [here](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql#creating-a-query). I would imagine you would then add them to your types inside `config/graphql.php` along with the regular types.

I would also suggest renaming the input to something like `SongPartInput` so you don't get confused if you also have a type for SongPart.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I created new type SongPartInput with $inputObject set to true. I hadn't noticed this variable.